# One Function works on different tables

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a table generated in a backend. My task is to wrap text in each header column and add it to each body column cells by using .html() and .prepend(). It works as expected (you will see text in green).

Problem: If there are 2 independent tables in a page, it will be mess up. Green text in the first table looks as expected, but it will take header text from the first table and add to body column cells of second table as an image below:
[image]

The 2 tables should be like the image below
[image]

How to fix this issue, please give me a hand.  Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("table thead tr th").each(function(i) {
    let bodyCode = $("<span>", {
      text: $(this).text()
    });
    $(`table tbody tr td:nth-child(${i+1})`).prepend(bodyCode);
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray
}

span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Earn</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: So what *should* happen? Should only the first table get changed? Should both tables get changed? I'm unclear on what the final result needs to be

Comment: Hi j08691, sorry for a confuse! The final result should be like the image, which I just uploaded.  Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that you need to loop through each `table` first.

So this code:

1. Gets each `table` element in the `each`.
2. Gets the `th` elements in that specific table using `each`
3. Gets the text you want from the `th` element and sets it to `<span>` tag
4. Then gets the current `th` element, finds its parent (`table`), and then finds each `td` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Loop through each table
  $("table").each(function() {
    // find all the tds in each table
    let th = $(this).find('thead tr th');
    // Loop through each th in the table
    th.each(function(i) {
      let bodyCode = $("<span>", {
        text: $(this).text()
      });
      // find the td elements in this specific table.
      $(this).parents('table').find(`tbody td:nth-child(${i+1})`).prepend(bodyCode);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray
}

span {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Day</th>
      <th>Earn</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Monday</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Tuesday</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

<p> added extra tables for proof of concept</p>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
      <td>$200</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
<br>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, @disinfor so much for clearly explanations!  That works as expected.